# HP WebOS 3.0 Emulator, how to navigate

Tags: emulation, exit, webos, quit

does any know how i can exit a program in HP webOS 3.0 Emulator. There isn't any home button and i can not find answer anywhere with google. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using the "scroll wheel" on your mouse

(Added as an answer to help anyone in future)

Answer (score 3):

Same way as any webOS device: go to Card Mode (press the Home key for the Emulator) and toss the card off the top of the screen.   That's a bit harder with a mouse in the Emulator, than a finger on a device, but it's still doable.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but where is the "Home key for the Emulator"?

Comment: You can achieve this using the "scroll wheel" on your mouse

Comment: On a standard US 101-key keyboard, the "home" key is located between the "help" and "page up" keys, in the block of keys between the letter keys and the numeric keypad.

Comment: If the scroll wheel doesn't work for you, press the home key first. I think that was Doug's point.

Answer (score 1):

On a Macbook Pro, use <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> key to switch to card view and then you can use **mouse** / **touchpad** to throw it away.